# How do I use full text search across multiple tables, SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, multiple-tables

I have a full text catalog with two tables in it.

tableA has 4 columns (a1, a2, a3, a4) of which 3 are indexed in the catalog, a2,a3,a4.
a1 is the primary key.

tableB has 3 columns (b1, b2, b3, b4), two of which are indexed in the catalog, b3 and b4. b1 is the PK of this table, b2 is the FK to tableA.

I want to do something like

```
SELECT *, (ftTableA.[RANK] + ftTableB.[RANK]) AS total_rank 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.a1=tableB.b2
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(tableA, (a2,a3,a4), 'search term') as ftTableA ON tableA.a1=ftTableA.[KEY]
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(tableB, (b3,b4), 'search term') as ftTableB ON tableB.11=ftTableB.[KEY]
```

But this does not work...
I can get a single table to work, eg.

```
SELECT *, (ftTableA.[RANK] + ftTableB.[RANK]) AS total_rank 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(tableA, (a2,a3,a4), 'search term') as ftTableA ON tableA.a1=ftTableA.[KEY]
```

but never more than one table.

Could someone give an explanation and/or example of the steps required to full-text search over multiple tables.

Answer (score 4):

Your query only returns records, if both A and related B contains the search text.

You do not state what does not work, though.

Why not LEFT OUTER JOIN the fulltext searches, and replace:

```
SELECT *, (ISNULL(ftTableA.[RANK], 0) + ISNULL(ftTableB.[RANK], 0)) AS total_rank
```

and

```
WHERE ftTableA.Key IS NOT NULL OR ftTableB.Key IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive that I understood what you were trying to do.  I interpreted your question as you want to return all items in Table A that matched the search term.  Furthermore you wanted to sum the rank from the item in TableA plus the matching items in TableB.

The best way I can think to do this is to use a table variable with 3 queries.

```
DECLARE @Results Table (a1 Int UNIQUE, Rank Int)

--Insert into @Results all matching items from TableA
INSERT INTO @Results
(a1, Rank)
( SELECT TableA.a1, FT.Rank
FROM TableA INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(TableA, *, 'search term') FT
ON TableA.A1 = FT.[Key]
)

--Update all of the ranks in @Results with a sum of current value plus the sum of
--all sub items (in TableB)
UPDATE @Results
SET Rank = RS.Rank + FT.Rank
FROM @Results RS INNER JOIN TableB
ON RS.A1 = TableB.b2
INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(TableB, *, 'search term') FT
ON TableB.b1 = FT.[Key]

--Now insert into @Results any items that has a match in TableB but not in TableA
--This query may/may not be desired based on your business rules.
INSERT INTO @Results
(SkillKeyId, Rank)
( SELECT TableB.b2, Sum(FT.Rank)
FROM TableB INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(TableB, *, 'search term') FT
ON TableB.b1 = FT.[key]
LEFT JOIN @Results RS
ON RS.a1 = TableB.b2
WHERE RS.a1 IS NULL
GROUP BY TableB.b2
)

--All that's left is to return the results
SELECT TableA.*, RS.Rank AS Total_Rank
FROM TableA INNER JOIN @Results RS
ON TableA.a1 = RS.a1
ORDER BY RS.Rank DESC
```

This isn't as elegant as using one query, but it should be easy to follow and allows you to decide whether or not to include records in the 3rd query.