# Full text search on a table

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

How to enable and perform a "full text" search on a table in SQL Server 2005?

I did not quite understand the solution in: [How do I use full text search across multiple tables, SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206142/how-do-i-use-full-text-search-accross-multiple-tables-mssql-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How hard is it to incorporate full text search with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202440/how-hard-is-it-to-incorporate-full-text-search-with-sql-server#202474)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this [video tutorial](http://www.venexus.com/Support/Tutorials/SQLServerFullTextIndexing.aspx), should get you a good part of the way there.

you have to setup the index before you can search against it.

Comment: Thank You Mitchel, unfortunately I cannot mark 2 answers as right in SO

Answer (score -1):

You can also have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Begin to [Set Up SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Searching](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/1/4/Setting-Up-SQL-Server-2005-FullText-Searching).

Then do an overview about the functions you can use:

http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/1/4/Performing-SQL-Server-CONTAINS-Searches

http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/1/4/Performing-SQL-Server-FREETEXT-Searches

http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/1/5/Ranking-SQL-Server-2005-FullText-Search-Results